# DIV contenteditable and new lines

Tags: php, html, newline, contenteditable, nl2br

I'm using XPath to get div contenteditable's content and insert it in DB. But when I output the content there are no new lines.

```
$divs = $xpath->query('//div');
foreach($divs as $book) {
$text = nl2br($book->textContent);
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$book->textContent` strips all markup from the content [1], such as `<div>` which are naturally inserted when you hit enter on an `contenteditable`-Element. Therefore all this function returns is a concatenation of pure text.

I'm not sure what your goal is, but you might look into [`$your_DOMDocument->saveHTML($book)`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savehtml.php). This will return the actual HTML of each `$book` including the surrounding `<div>`.

[1]: see the [DOM Specifications](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-DOM-Level-3-Core-20040407/core.html#Node3-textContent)

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to set a `xml:whitespace="preserve"` attribute on the element that has content editable and it come through using the xml api.

Failing this a solution would be to add a keypress handler to the content editable div that catches an enter and replaces it with a `<br/>` at the cursor position.